# Google Search Console API: HttpError 403

Tags: javascript, python, api, google-analytics, google-api-webmasters

I am trying to get data from GSC Search Analytics API using Python. 
I have been following [this guide](https://moz.com/ugc/how-to-get-the-data-you-need-from-googles-search-analytics-api), but no matter how many times I tried to change something I keep getting this error:

```
 raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com/searchAnalytics/query?alt=json returned "User does not have sufficient permission for
site 'http://www.example.com/'. See also: https://support.google.co
m/webmasters/answer/2451999.">
```

I gave full permission to the email address generated in for the service account in Google developers console  [user permission screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U00Oq.png)

I do get Google Analytics report retrieved with all the data, but google search console report is empty due to this permission issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pass the domain URL of which you have access. Not www.example.com

Comment: I have tried these 2 so far, but I have 30 more sites under same GSC and GA accounts:  
http://www.humberviewmotorsports.com/ 
http://www.woodstockhyundai.com/

Answer (score 2):

For those who do not know, as it is said [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/add), passing your website URL in your query matters.

> The URL of the property to add. Examples: http://www.example.com/ (for a URL-prefix property) or sc-domain:example.com (for a Domain property)